# jQuery ScrollTo won't work

Tags: jquery, magento

Good afternoon,
I'm experimenting jQuery scrollto function using Magento CMS.

I created a page using the following HTML structure (reference this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/VPzxG/)

```
    function goToByScroll(id){
      // Reove "link" from the ID
    id = id.replace("link", "");
      // Scroll
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top},
        'slow');
}

$("#sidebar > ul > li > a").click(function(e) { 
      // Prevent a page reload when a link is pressed
    e.preventDefault(); 
      // Call the scroll function
    goToByScroll($(this).attr("id"));           
});
```

what I get once I load the page is a firebug error

> TypeError: $(...) is null
>
> $("#sidebar > ul > li > a").click(function(e) {

If I click on any of the menu instead of scrolling to the correct ID it load the magento home page.
For example if I click on the first link "auck" it load http://www.magentoscrolltest.dev/#

As I have understand is like Magento CMS is not recognizing jQuery in my script, but I don't know how to proceed further.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses Prototype which also uses the `$`. You'll have to either use jQuery with noConflict or write `jQuery` instead of the `$` sign.

If you want to use noConflict try using (the example means you'll have to use `$j` from now on):

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 

$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j("#test").css("padding","10px");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Adam, so is for Prototype that didn't work. I fixed my script as following

[code] var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); 
$j(document).ready(function(){[/code]

but still not work

Comment: I updated and tested again with your suggestion (http://jsfiddle.net/oL9w1rrk/2/) now in Firebug console I don't see the error like before, but Magento CMS still open the page link # instead of scrolling down. Do I need any other libraries apart of jQuery? Currently I use jQuery 1.9.1. Thanks